# Socket.IO 1.2.0 client rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

When I disconnect from a Socket.IO server, the socket has no rooms in the `clientSocket.rooms` array. How can I get the rooms he has and will be disconnected from. Does the disconnect from rooms happen before the disconnect event on the socket and is there a way to get the rooms?

Comment: Ok, only i could do was creating my own join and leave methods to follow last status of rooms for each socket.

Comment: What did you do if the client is disconnected because of a closed app/browser window?

Comment: @NoahB i did the same thing as in first comment. It doesnt matter how client disconnects from server. Disconnect works the same.

Comment: So you customized the methods in the socket.io library code? (Otherwise, how were your methods called before the disconnect if the browser is just closed?)

Comment: @NoahB you call them on callbacks. You should not probably override the methods. Have rooms = {}. On connect callback set rooms[socketRoom].push(socket) and on disconnect callback rooms[socketRoom].pop(socket). Js isnt 100% perfect but this is just to present idea.